# Regex-transformation with text and numbers

Tags: regex

I am having troubles making my regex-statement to work as intended.

Regex statement: `([a-z][a-z\d]+)(?=([A-Z][a-z\d]+))`

Starting string: `regex2Hard4Me`

current result: `REGEX2_HARD4_ME`

desirable result: `REGEX_2_HARD_4_ME`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This `([a-z][a-z\d]+)` is letters followed by a number, all together. Why are you putting them all together if your desired result is the letters separated from the number? What about matching just the number `\(d+)` and replacing it with `_\1_` the match with underlines?

Comment: HI there, you unaccepted the answer, did it not work out?

Comment: Sorry, missclick! Accepted again now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match a single char a-z or digit, and assert a char A-Z or digit to the right:

```
[a-z0-9](?=[A-Z0-9])
```

In the replacement use the full match followed by an underscore.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1pTTc/1)

Output

```
regex_2_Hard_4_Me
```

Then uppercase the string to get `REGEX_2_HARD_4_ME`